# What JMS versions does Amazon MQ support?

Tags: amazon-mq

Is anyone using Amazon MQ (Message Broker Service managed by AWS) with JMS 3?

As part of our Tomcat 10 migration journey we realized that we cannot use ActiveMQ "Classic" any more (since Tomcat 10 drops JMS 2 support, if I read their documentation right). We were thinking for a long time to move our message broker to Amazon MQ (from ActiveMQ) and hopefully stop worrying about that part of our infrastructure. So my question is does Amazon MQ support JMS 3? Could we switch to it as part of our Tomcat 10 migration journey? Or will have to use other JMS 3 compliant brokers (e.g. ActiveMQ Artemis) until Amazon adds support for JMS 3?

Comment: Got it! Thanks Justin! And since we seem to be using OpenWire protocol for communication with AMQ I guess we are bound to the specific implementation. It's not a best practice to use OpenWire protocol, right? Messaging is not the crucial part of our application so definitely not my area of expertise, but am wondering if it would be worth for us to bite the bullet and switch to more implementation independent protocols like AMQP for communication with AMQ? What would be the trade offs?

Comment: Typically with JMS applications the wire protocol doesn't actually matter since the API is consistent. Application developers can change JMS providers as long as they stick to the API. Therefore, I wouldn't say, "It's not a best practice to use OpenWire protocol..." Of course AMQP is an ISO standard wire protocol, but I'm not sure how much that actually buys you if you're just using JMS.

Comment: You may want to reword your question because you've got multiple distinct questions here which means your question is liable to be closed. FWIW, I tried to answer the question in the title which I assumed was the "real" question.

Answer (score 1):

Amazon MQ supports ActiveMQ "Classic" and RabbitMQ "engine types" as noted in [their documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazon-mq/latest/developer-guide/welcome.html). Therefore whatever those brokers support is what Amazon MQ can support.

To be clear, JMS is an *API*. The wire-level protocol 100% depends on the implementation.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a Jakarta Messaging v3.1.0 client by using the new Jakarta-based client released in 5.18.1.

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.activemq</groupId>
  <groupId>activemq-client-jakarta</groupId>
  <version>5.18.1</version>
</dependency>
```

Most of the newer JMS 2.0 features (also used by Jakarta Messaging v3.1.0) are available in ActiveMQ 5.18.x you can track this page to monitor progress of the remaining features:

Jakarta / JMS 2 feature status: https://activemq.apache.org/jms2

Comment: Thanks Matt! Will definitely keep an eye on it! Currently it doesn't support all the features we use, but might be worth waiting until support is added rather than switching to other JMS Alternatives.

Comment: What feature is missing?

Answer (score 0):

As of February 2024, AWS is using ActiveMQ Classic version 5.17.6 for its [AmazonMQ service](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazon-mq/latest/developer-guide/activemq-version-management.html).

Unfortunately, this version lacks support for JMS 2.0 or Jakarta 3.1. Only JMS 1.1 is supported.

JMS 2.0/Jakarta 3.1 functionalities started to be introduced with ActiveMQ version 5.18. You can find a list of features and their corresponding versions in the [ActiveMQ documentation](https://activemq.apache.org/components/classic/documentation/jms2) .

As of now, there is no public disclosure from Amazon regarding their plans to upgrade AmazonMQ to ActiveMQ Classic 5.18/6.